# TypeError: iniciar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um programa simples, de controle de gastos em Python, com interface gráfica, o PySimpleGUI, o aplicativo até é executado pelo PyCharm, mas depois que fecho o app, ele não retorna os dados, apenas esse erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\User\Desktop\finin\finan.py", line 31, in 
> TelaPython.iniciar() TypeError: iniciar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Trecho do código:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class TelaPython:
    def _init_(self):
        self.values = 'values'
        self.button = 'button'
    pass


layout = [
        [sg.Text('Quanto você ganhou hoje?')],
        [sg.Text('Data:   '), sg.Input(size=(16, 0), key='data')],
        [sg.Text('Ganhos:'),sg.Input(size=(15,3), key='ganhos')],
        [sg.Text('Gastos:'), sg.Input(size=(15,0),key='gastos')],
        [sg.Button('Calcular', key='calcular')]
]

janela = sg.Window("Dados do Usuário").layout(layout)

button, values = janela.Read()

def iniciar(self):
    data = self.values['data']
    ganhos = self.values['ganhos']
    gastos = self.values['gastos']
    print(f'data: {data}')
    print(f'ganhos: {ganhos}')
    print(f'gastos: {gastos}')


TelaPython.iniciar()
```

Comment: Sua classe `TelaPython` não tem o método `iniciar` estático. Isso significa que você precisa de uma instância dessa classe como objeto: `tela_python = TelaPython()`. Dessa forma, você pode acessar o método através do objeto: `tela_python.iniciar()`.

Comment: Valeu amigo, deu super certo!

Comment: A declaração da classe `TelaPython` se resume apenas ao método `_init_()`, todo o resto do código está fora do contexto da classe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Erros

No seu código você está chamando o método `iniciar()` da classe `TelaPython()`, através do comando `TelaPython.iniciar()`, com isto o seu sistema acha que tem um método chamado `iniciar()` na sua classe, porém se você analisar o seu código, não contém o método `iniciar()` dentro da sua classe.
Um outro erro que contém o seu código é o `button` calcular que quando clica não exibe os dados de `data, ganhos e gastos`, ou seja não tem um `event` para o seu `button`  calcular para exibir os dados.

### Código

Elaborei um código que não contém os erros descritos acima. Obs: após você clicar no botão de calcular ele exibe os dados no console e não fecha a interface gráfica.

Código:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg  
  
  
def telaPython():  
    layout = [  
            [sg.Text('Quanto você ganhou hoje?')],  
            [sg.Text('Data:   '), sg.Input(size=(16, 0), key='data')],  
            [sg.Text('Ganhos:'),sg.Input(size=(15,3), key='ganhos')],  
            [sg.Text('Gastos:'), sg.Input(size=(15,0),key='gastos')],  
            [sg.Button('Calcular', key='calcular')]  
    ]  
  
    return sg.Window("Dados do Usuário", layout, finalize=True)  
  
janela = telaPython()  
  
while True:  
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()  
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:  
        break  
  
     if event == 'calcular':  
        print(f'data: {values["data"]}')  
        print(f'ganhos: {values["ganhos"]}')  
        print(f'gastos: {values["gastos"]}')
```

Resultado após executar o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mais detalhes sobre o PySimpleGUI, basta acessar este site [PySimpleGui](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/)

Comment: Deu certo! Mas sem querer ser chato, você sabe como faço operações matemáticas com o PySimpleGUI, justamente por ter que calcular os valores. Sou iniciante em interface gráfica no Python, se puder ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: Opa man! Na hora que clica no seu botão calcular, o código entra no `if event == 'calcular':`, com base nisto você pode pegar os valores do campo `data, ganhos e gastos`, utilizando o values["nome da key do campo"] e com isto você pode fazer operações.

Comment: Amigo, você consegue elaborar um pouco mais, por favor? Ainda não peguei muito.

Comment: Você pode fazer operações utilizando os values dos campos. Por exemplo: Digamos que eu queira fazer uma operação de subtração com o campo "ganhos" e com o campo "gastos", com base nisto eu tenho que pegar o valor do "ganhos" utilizando o `values['ganhos']`  e o valor do "gastos" utilizando o `values['gastos']`, tendo os dois valores basta eu fazer `values['ganhos']` - `values['gastos']` para obter o resultado da subtração.

Comment: Fiz um código exemplo. Acessa este site e cola o código no seu programa http://codepad.org/2A2KrKdq e confira como que faz as operações matemáticas. =)

Comment: @KaiqueNakao, nesse caso você pode orientar o AP a criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Valeu meu amigo funcionou, muito obrigado, de verdade! Se precisar estou aqui. Valeu!